# "Thousands-Dollar" or "Thousand-Dollar"?

Tags: word-usage

If a prize is worth thousands of dollars, is it called

> a **thousands**-dollar prize

or

> a **thousand**-dollar prize

Answer (score 2):

you would never use 'thousands-dollar' as that expression is not used in English. 'there is a thousand-dollar prize' is correct for $1,000. For more than $1,000 you would have to say, for example 'there is a five thousand-dollar prize', giving the actual sum, or use a more indirect way, such as 'the prize is worth many thousands of dollars', or 'the prize is worth several thousand dollars'. 'The prize is worth a few thousand dollars' is also correct. I hope this is helpful, as I am not able to explain the grammatical rule.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think either of those sounds correct. Thousand dollar prize means $1000 to me. In the question the prize is more than $1000.

Instead of using either, you could try re-phrasing like in your question:

"The prize is worth thousands of dollars."

If the prize is $5000, you could say "Five Thousand Dollar Prize".

Comment: @sumelic Because it's worth more than $1K?

Comment: I'm making a video game and I can't decide which one is correct for an achievement name.

Comment: Thousand dollar prize means $1000 to me. In the question the prize is more than $1000